# AJAX - dont know how to append function

Tags: asp.net, ajax, entity-framework, jquery

i have to functions - one client function and another server side function.
this is the server side function:

```
[WebMethod]
public IList<OrderViewDTO> GetTaskProgress(DateTime xDATEx)
{
    try
    {
        var xDate2 = xDATEx.AddDays(1);
        var q = new OrderDataRepository()
            .GetAllOrderData()
            .Where(x=>x.POD_DATE>=xDATEx && x.POD_DATE < xDate2)
            .GroupBy(o => o.User)
            .Select(g => new OrderViewDTO
            {
                DriverId = g.Key.Id,
                PdriverName = g.Key.Name,
                OrderCount = g.Count(),
                OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull = g.Count(o => o.RECEIVE_NAME != null)
            })
            .ToList();
        return q;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw WrapException(e);
    }
}
```

and this is the client side function 
what changes do i have to make so the client side function will call the server side function
?

```
                 _Services.invoke({
                     method: 'GetTaskProgress',
                     data: { xDATEx: date1 },
                     success: function (q) {
                          paint(q);
                     }

 function paint(orders) {
            var table=
                        '<table>';
            $.each(orders, function() {
                        table +=
                                    '<tr>'+
                                                '<td>'+this.DriverId +'</td>'+
                                                '<td>'+this.PdriverName +'</td>'+
                                                '<td>'+this.OrderCount +'</td>'+
                                                '<td>'+this.OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull +'</td>'+
                                    '</tr>';
            });
            table+=
                        '</table>';
            table=$(table);
            div.append(table);
}
```

Comment: Hey, stop screaming=) Only using uppercase makes the text rather hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not.
You're mixing server side C# with client side javascript.

Your web method needs to return Json formatted data, which your client side javascript can then consume.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515101.aspx for an example.

Comment: ok i have changed the code into 2 functions - how can i connect between them now? i mean how the client side function call the server side and how to get back values? please check my code above